# Can you transfer data as UTF-16?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a program that uses 128-bit identifiers. The data is UTF-8 encoded JSON.

To reduce payload size, can I treat an id as UTF-16, convert it to UTF-8, and send that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Some combinations of bytes will result in invalid UTF-16 "characters", such as ones in the surrogate region U+D800 to U+DFFF. These codepoints are not valid outside a surrogate pair, and their UTF-8 encodings are treated as invalid by most software.

Comment: When you say "they're treated as invalid", what is the effect of that? The JSON won't parse at all? There are UTF-16 documents that can't be represented as UTF-8?

Comment: Another take: Random bytes won't typically be valid UTF-8 data, and they often won't be valid UTF-16 either. Since it's not valid UTF-16, it can't be converted into valid UTF-8.